# Sequence of continuous function converge uniformly to continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

**Theorem:** Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions. If $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$, then $f$ is continuous.

I don't like the Rudin's approach, then I try to do my own way, but it seems to be wrong.

**Proof:** By definitions, we have:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0$$
$$\exists n_1\in\mathbb{N}; n>n_1 \Rightarrow ||f_n(x)-f(x)||<\varepsilon/3$$
$$\exists n_2\in\mathbb{N}; n>n_2 \Rightarrow ||f_n(a)-f(a)||<\varepsilon/3$$
$$\exists \delta > 0; ||x-a||<\delta \Rightarrow ||f_n(x)-f_n(a)||<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

Put $n_0 = \max\{n_1,n_2\}$. Then we have

$$n>n_0 \text{ and } ||x-a||<\delta \Rightarrow ||f(x)-f_n(x)||+||f_n(a)-f(a)||+||f_n(x)-f_n(a)|| < \varepsilon$$

By triangular inequality:

$$||f(x)-f(a)||<\epsilon \text{  } \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third step, $\delta$ is not necessarily the same for all $n$, i.e. $\delta = \delta_{n,\varepsilon,a}$ depends on $\varepsilon, a$ **and** $n$. So indeed, your proof is incorrect.

At a high-level, I'd encourage you to be more rigorous with the quantifiers (you miss the quantifiers relating to $n$ in the third part), and to write out explicitly the dependencies whenever possible ("$\exists \delta = \delta_{n,\varepsilon,a}$" for instance).

*PS:* last comment: in your first two statements, there should be no $x$. $f_n$, $f$ are functions; $f_n(x)$, $f(x)$ here are not .

Comment: Thanks, I will read more about sequence of function... This is 'obscure' to me yet.

Comment: @RenanR. Additionally, if this answered your question, consider marking it as such (by using the checkmark on the left). If not, then of course do not (but please, let me know how to improve my answer :))

Comment: Sorry, I was marked it but for some reason that isn't work :/ I'll try again

Comment: No worries! ${}{}{}$